# List kubernetes persistent volume claims with python API by filtered by age

Tags: python, kubernetes

Was looking to find kubernetes pvc which are older than certain time limit and remove.
Couldn't find enough resource on web. Any idea?

Anybody knows what might be the right attribute?

This is the script version to list all pvc:

```
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()

pvcs = v1.list_persistent_volume_claim_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
print("---- PVCs ---")
print("%-16s\t%-40s\t%-6s" % ("Name", "Volume", "Size"))
for pvc in pvcs.items:
    print("%-16s\t%-40s\t%-6s" %
            (pvc.metadata.name, pvc.spec.volume_name,    
            pvc.spec.resources.requests['storage']))
```

Edit:
Solution for now:

```
from kubernetes import client, config, watch
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
import os, subprocess

#----------------------------------------------------
now = datetime.utcnow()
only_date = now.date()
print (" ")
print ("Today's date is:", (only_date))
print (" ")
retention_days = 0
#------------------------------------------------------

ns = os.getenv("K8S_NAMESPACE")
if ns is None:
    ns = "foo" # Namespace foo is aleady existing, or enter namespace

config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()

pvcs = v1.list_namespaced_persistent_volume_claim(namespace=ns, watch=False)
print("---- PVCs ---")
print("%-16s\t%-40s\t%-6s\t%-6s" % ("Name", "Volume", "Size", "Date_Created"))
for pvc in pvcs.items:
    print("%-16s\t%-40s\t%-6s\t%-6s" %
            (pvc.metadata.name, pvc.spec.volume_name,    
            pvc.spec.resources.requests['storage'], pvc.metadata.creation_timestamp.date()))
print("")
filtered_pvcs_date = pvc.metadata.creation_timestamp.date() 


if (only_date - filtered_pvcs_date) > timedelta(retention_days):
    print ("PVC is older than configured retention of %d days" % (retention_days))
    
    cmd = ('kubectl delete pvc' + " " + pvc.metadata.name + " " + '-n' + " " + ns)
    os.system(cmd) 
    
    
else:
    print ("PVC is younger than configured retention of %d days" % (retention_days))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [metadata.creation_timestamp](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/common-definitions/object-meta/#Read-only) field to check when an object was created:

```python
pvcs = v1.list_persistent_volume_claim_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)

#filter out all pvcs that have been created before 2021-04-25 18:25:30+00:00 (UTC)
from datetime import datetime, timezone
filtered_pvcs = [pvc for pvc in pvcs.items if pvc.metadata.creation_timestamp > 
    datetime(2021, 4, 25, 18, 25, 30, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc)]

for pvc in filtered_pvcs:
    print ...
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try that!